# What is the difference between the Query class and the Gqlquery class in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Are they just different interfaces to the same underlying query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697049/what-is-the-difference-between-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine)

Answer (score 1):

[snippet from http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html]
As with the Query class, the application executes the query and accesses results either by calling the fetch() method, or by treating the GqlQuery object as an iterable. See the Query documentation for more information.

There is one difference between how Query and GqlQuery access results: If the GQL query includes a LIMIT clause or an OFFSET clause, results are retrieved as with the equivalent fetch() method, even if the iterator interface is used to access the results. When a GqlQuery whose GQL contains LIMIT or OFFSET is used as an iterable, one call is made to the datastore to fetch all of the results, and the iterator returns each of the results from memory.