# Alternative to user defined functions in Google's Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I just transferred my database to Google's Cloud SQL, but as stated in the [FAQ on Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures), it says user defined functions are not supported. I am using a function called Levenshtein, taken from this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql), to perform a search on a dictionary that I created in my database. It is a function that can find words that look similar (including misspellings) and returns the distance from a given word.

Does Google offer any alternatives to user defined functions that would allow me to use this functionality to perform search?

Comment: No it doesn't. However you could use gce and in there use any database you want.

Comment: Yes, CloudSQL is essentially sandboxed MySQL so simply running MySQL (or another DB) on a Compute Engine instance might be your best solution.

Comment: is a lame that Google does not support this, one of the reason i could consider a Cloud based infrastructure would be the ability to migrate my db to CloudSQL to take advantage of power, performance and scalability so I  base my app on UDF and stored procedures.

Comment: Apparently if you use GCE (Google Cloud Engine) you can completely control your database. But you cannot do this using GAE (Google App Engine). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697049/what-is-the-difference-between-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine for more about the difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are confused about terminology:

- **User Defined Function** = A function defined in real code, compiled into a DLL/SO, and created in MySQL with [`CREATE FUNCTION ... SONAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html). This is not possible in Cloud SQL.
- **Stored Procedure** = A function defined in SQL statements, and created in MySQL with [`CREATE FUNCTION routine_body`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html) or `CREATE PROCEDURE`. This is allowed in Cloud SQL.

I just tested this out by copying and pasting the [definition from that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928762/3645370) into my Cloud SQL instance and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Agreed. I meant Stored Procedure. I tested the code from the SO article and it gave some SQL errors, but it did create the function however. Thanks for the help!