# Google Cloud supported datatypes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-sql

What are all the datatypes that Google Cloud SQL does provide?

I am migrating a database so I wanted to know the datatypes supported by Google Cloud.
And if there is any official link, kindly provide that.

Comment: you could improve your question by showing the best link you have found so far and tell the types you really need. otherwise this looks like a routine job you are just to lazy to work out yourself, not a type of question that is liked very much.

Comment: Eg: whether it supports Stored procedure, Views, Functions, Triggers.. etc

Comment: i Couldnt find any so i asked, if u have kindly answer

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715273/alternative-to-user-defined-functions-in-googles-cloud-sql or https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the **official documentation**, Cloud SQL provides the same functionality provided by a locally-hosted MySQL/PostgreSQL instance; nevertheless, it is important to note that there are some unsupported features and statements when using the Cloud SQL versions, you can take a look on the following links to know more about this matter:

- [Differences between Cloud SQL and standard MySQL functionality](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#differences)
- [Differences between Cloud SQL and standard PostgreSQL functionality](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#differences-pg)

Additionally, you may want to review the [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html) Data Types documentation where you can find detail information about the data types supported by the latest versions.