# Google Drive: How to get service account email when downloaded as p12

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I am integrating my application with drive using service account. When I create a service account and download as p12, how can I show the email address and other key-val pairs that I get when downloaded as json?

When I click the downloaded p12 file, it is a certificate so a wizard to import it opens where I enter the given password "notasecret". And it gets imported in mmc under Local Machine (tried current user also). But I am not sure how to get the email and keyfilepath (I assume this to be the path where this cert is stored) from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the email address from the P12 or JSON file, perform the following steps:

1. Go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Select "API Manager" on the top corner drop-down menu.
3. Next, select "Credentials" on the side menu.
4. If "Service account key" is created, click on "Manage service accounts" on the far right. You should see the following screenshot with the *Email address* for service account. There you go :) [image]

Comment: Ah Thanks @Andres. And I see that there are no keys for Compute engine but has for app engine. What does keys mean? And what is the difference between app engine and compute engine default service account?

Comment: According to the source, if your application runs on Google App Engine, a service account is set up automatically when you create your project. Hence, you probably see a key for your App Engine service account. You can read more about Service Account at this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Also, check out this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697049/what-is-the-difference-between-google-app-engine-and-google-compute-engine) post that explains the difference between app engine and compute engine. Good luck and Go Gators! :)

Comment: Awesome. @Andreas: Thank you so much. Go Gators :-) :-)