# Django application freezes on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm having some trouble with a Django application deployed on Google App Engine.

I still don't know how to replicate the issue.

It seems like the application randomly freezes. It just stops responding (no log is produced in the meanwhile) and, if I go in any application page, I get this error:

**Error: Server Error**

**The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.**

**Please try again in 30 seconds.**

No error is shown in the logs and the only strange warning I found is this one:

**OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k**

I don't have any issues when I run the application on my Ubuntu machine.

I'm using Django 2.1.5 with Python 3.7 and Django connects to a MySQL instance (on Google Cloud SQL).

**Additional information:**

The *app.yaml* file is very basic and is taken straight from the [official example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/django/app.yaml):

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37
service: backend

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

# [END django_app]
```

**Excerpt of Django configuration:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_filters',
    'django_rest_passwordreset',
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'rest_framework_filters.backends.RestFrameworkFilterBackend',
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ],
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=10),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': "XXXXXX",
}
```

It's worth noting that there are custom installed apps that access the MySQL database both using the usual Django ORM and by directly querying a number of different databases using the **pymysql** library.

Comment: Need more detail about your configuration. Can you post your `app.yaml` (obsfucating any private data)?

Comment: I updated the question with additional information. I'm not sure what else could be useful, so any suggestion is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppEngine warning - OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016899/appengine-warning-openblas-warning-could-not-determine-the-l2-cache-size-on)