# AWS Lambda and S3 - OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So, I need to trigger a Lambda function every time a new file is uploaded to an S3 Bucket.

I created the Lambda function in Cloud 9 with no trigger (only API Gateway available there), and then added the trigger in the yaml file and created the event in the S3 bucket.

When I test the function locally in C9 it works fine, but when I trigger ir uploading a file to S3 the logs show this warning:

```
OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
```

and the function times out.

The memory was at 128MB, but I tried increasing it and the problem persists.

Comment: could you provide the logs messages from CloudWatch?. It is on the `Monitoring` tab of the lambda function.

Comment: That error and the fact that the function times out are the only logs. If I comment out all the code inside the function and just print something, the function executes and works, but still with the warning. I have Pandas installed, and I think this has something to do with package size? I'm at about 400MB. Don't understand how it lets me deploy when the limit is supposed to be 250MB

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016899/appengine-warning-openblas-warning-could-not-determine-the-l2-cache-size-on).

Pandas consumes a lot of memory, more than what the instances in your application can handle, and fails with the error you posted.
There are other issues in your Lambda function, other than the `OpenBLAS`, you might need to fix. As most functions sometimes still work with this warning. The only impact it would have is slightly reduced performance. Review your application code and dependencies in case you can decrease memory consumption. Increasing the memory configuration might be helpful if you can't decrease memory consumption.

References:

1. [AppEngine warning - OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016899/appengine-warning-openblas-warning-could-not-determine-the-l2-cache-size-on)
2. ["OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k" after setting instance to max(B8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533585/openblas-warning-could-not-determine-the-l2-cache-size-on-this-system-assumi)
3. [AWS Lambda : OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k - While using Google Custom Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57087498/aws-lambda-openblas-warning-could-not-determine-the-l2-cache-size-on-this-sy)