# Google Cloud Function not deploying on GCP Cloud functions - Function failed on loading user code

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-cloud-functions

I have my python code that works fine on my machine. However, when deploying it on GCP with the correct requirements it is not deploying as it should.
I have resolved all error and now i am just left with the below error

[image]

[image]

I've not seen this error and cant seem to solve it - has anyone else seen this error?

Comment: Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68868732/15774176) :

> Serverless environments such as App Engine, Cloud Functions and Cloud Run, run in a sandbox, similar to gVisor. This sandbox protects the system from
> malicious calls and blocks some low level instruction. This one to get the CPU capabilities should be discarded.
> I got the same when I ran Tensorflow Serving on Cloud Run.

This error has been discussed in the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1092635/667978):

> The warning is just telling you that [OpenBLAS](https://www.openblas.net/), which is a dependency of Pandas, is not able to determine some settings of Cloud Function environments,
> most likely due to Cloud Function runs on virtualized environments. I suggest that you just ignore the warning as it is not an issue in Cloud Function.

For more information, you can refer to a well explained [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55175286/15774176) on the similar issue.