# VM-based automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter. standard_scheduler_settings.max_instances

Tags: asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

After a hefting bill from leaving my project turn on for 7 days in GCloud i decided to look for an explanation. I found that app.yaml wasnt configure so that it uses the basic minimum spec. So i found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125661/pricing-of-google-app-engine-flexible-env-a-500-lesson)
I am trying to deploy asp .net core app into GAE using `gcloud app deploy` but i am facing this issue! What i am doing wrong here as i think i am following the correct syntax as in the google docs
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/reference/app-yaml

[image]

app.yaml

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 0
  max_num_instances: 1
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
  target_concurrent_requests: 100
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I tried this version from [Pricing of Google App Engine Flexible env, a $500 lesson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125661/pricing-of-google-app-engine-flexible-env-a-500-lesson) but i manage to get it to work on the first try but after following deployment i kept getting the same error above.

**The version that work the first time round**

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  min_instances: 0
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Comment: Are you saying the error you posted is from the value of your app.yaml where you have the parameter - ```max_num_instances```? I ask because your error message talks about ```max_instances``` but you don't have that in what you posted as your current ```app.yaml``` file. Also, if you're trying to cut down on the hefty bill you received, I'm curious as to why you want to have up to 15 instances running

Comment: ahh my bad, let me correct that

Comment: @NoCommandLine No matter what i use as a syntax ```max_instances``` or ```max_num_instances``` the error will be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration seems to work in the end and i found out that i cannot set `min_num_instances` to 0

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
  target_concurrent_requests: 100
inbound_services:
- warmup
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the `min_num_instances`, since in Flex environment there can't be zero instances, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#scaling_characteristics):

> The standard environment can scale from zero instances up to thousands
> very quickly. In contrast, the flexible environment must have at least
> one instance running for each active version

Changing the value of the parameter to greater than zero should help to fix the error